# Facebook like social plugin for joomla article content

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, joomla2.5

I have an Article in joomla2.5 . I know it is possible to attach a facebook like social plugin for every article and there are numerous extensions available for that as well ( eg. JFBconnect ) , but I would like to know if it is possible to attach a different facebook like for different parts of that article content ?

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FB like uses the URL of the page so a single page can only contain a single Like instance. You could have multiple likes on a page in the case of a category listing page since each of the articles/items has a unique URL.